# subplot error in Matplotlib using seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting subplots of heatmap using seaborn with the following stripped down code. I get "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'spines'" if I use nrows=2 and ncols=2, the plot works if either of nrows or ncols=1. How do I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, axes  = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
sns.heatmap(Lpnl['19'],ax=axes[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: looks like you're potentially using pandas dataframes; have you considered using a `seaborn.FacetGrid` instead of subplots?

Comment: @Constantino: Would you be a able to suggest me or point to a link on how to plot multiple heatmaps with FacetGrid?

Comment: start going through the `FacetGrid` documentation, it's quite good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `axes` variable is a 2x2 numpy array. So when you do `axes[0]`, it is giving you the first row. I assume you want `axes[0, 0]` or `axes.flat[0]`.